# Ordine delle parole nell’espressione “ne si è bevuto molto”

Tags: grammar, pronouns, word-order, particles

Leggendo una pagina di grammatica, ho trovato  questa frase e non riesco a capire perché il “ne” viene messo prima del “si”:
“Di vino, ne si è bevuto poco”. In un altro esempio si può leggere “Degli errori, se ne è discusso ieri”, e questo esempio sì lo capisco bene, ma allora perché nell'esempio precedente si dice “ne si è bevuto poco” e non “se ne è bevuto poco”?

Comment: Qual è la fonte di questa frase? La combinazione "ne si" mi suona strana e, infatti, non appare in questa [tabella dell'Enciclopedia Treccani che elenca le combinazioni di due clitici che si usano](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/clitici_(Enciclopedia-dell'Italiano)/#gallery-in-text-5).

Comment: A naso direi che è un toscanismo.

Comment: Per me, "ne si è bevuto poco" è inusuale, ma non per questo sbagliato o incapibile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Se ne è bevuto poco" è quello che direbbe e scriverebbe qualunque italiano.
"Ne si" sarà una forma arcaica o una licenza poetica in azione.

Comment: Questa risposta migliorerebbe con alcune fonti a sostegno delle tue affermazioni. Puoi usare, per esempio, la tabella della Treccani menzionata nel mio commento alla domanda. Con la funzione "ricerca in sequenza" del *Grande dizionario della lingua italiana* puoi trovare alcuni esempi arcaici o poetici di uso della combinazione "ne si" che potresti aggiungere al tuo post.

Comment: Grazie per per avermi fornito un tale strumento. Imparerò a farne uso